# App Crashed When Setting Preferences

Tags: c++

This app I'm trying to debug has only one problem:  It crashes after I try to set a Preferences setting.  Make any change to Preferences, and it crashes.  Run it manually and it gives no error at the crash:

```
$ /usr/local/src/knet/knet
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
$
```

It is very active when I run it with strace, so I can't narrow down the cause in the morass of messages.  The only clue I really have is an error during cmake compile:

```
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/knet.dir/knetconfig.o
/usr/local/src/knet/knetconfig.cpp:192:56: warning: unused parameter ‘configFile’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void KnetConfig::writeNameOfConfigFile( const QString& configFile )
```

This is knetconfig.cpp:
http://pastebin.com/Su0PawFg

Edit: This seems to be my point of failure:

```
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\34\0\255\10J\0\300\v\213\1\0\0\271\233\271\16\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 576
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\1\274\10\0\0\0\0R\0\300\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(6, 0x7fffc90cf1a0, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(6, [{"O\7\2\0\1\0\300\v<\0\2\0\0\0\300\v+\1\1\0", 20}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 20
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\1\277\10\0\0\0\0R\0\300\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(6, 0x7fffc90cf180, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(6, 0x7fffc90cf180, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
shutdown(6, SHUT_RDWR)                  = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(8, "\1\v\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 16
close(8)                                = 0
write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
read(6, "0-7\n", 8192)                  = 4
close(6)                                = 0
write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
sendmsg(7, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1D\0\0\0\v\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 144}, {"?\0\0\0type='signal',interface='org"..., 68}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 212
msync(0x7f6624d95000, 10547304, MS_ASYNC|MS_INVALIDATE) = 0
munmap(0x7f6624d95000, 10547304)        = 0
sendmsg(7, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\1\1d\0\0\0\f\0\0\0\177\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 144}, {"_\0\0\0type='signal',path='/KGlobal"..., 100}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 244
close(7)                                = 0
write(5, "@", 1)                        = 1
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {0x7f6637867350, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO|SA_NOCLDSTOP, 0x7f6636b740f0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f6636b740f0}, NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
~$
```

Running it with xtrace, I right-click and About, which comes up fine, but when I Close that, it crashes thus:

```
000:>:06b4: Event PropertyNotify(28) window=0x06a0004a atom=0x23("WM_HINTS") time=0x0311b0bd state=Deleted(0x01)
000:>:06b4: Event PropertyNotify(28) window=0x06a0004a atom=0x28("WM_NORMAL_HINTS") time=0x0311b0bd state=Deleted(0x01)
000:>:06b4: Event PropertyNotify(28) window=0x06a0004a atom=0x24("WM_CLIENT_MACHINE") time=0x0311b0bd state=Deleted(0x01)
000:>:06b4: Event PropertyNotify(28) window=0x06a0004a atom=0x22("WM_COMMAND") time=0x0311b0bd state=Deleted(0x01)
000:>:06b4:32: Reply to GetInputFocus: revert-to=PointerRoot(0x01) focus=0x02c00052
000:<:06b5:  8: Request(79): FreeColormap cmap=0x06a00001
000:<:06b6:  8: Request(60): FreeGC gc=0x06a00000
000:<:06b7:  4: Request(43): GetInputFocus 
000:>:06b7:32: Reply to GetInputFocus: revert-to=PointerRoot(0x01) focus=0x02c00052
$
```

Here's all my source:

CMakeLists.txt - https://pastee.org/bux2z

frames.cpp - https://pastee.org/25yys

frames.h - https://pastee.org/qx9n2

knet.cpp - https://pastee.org/zqrss

knet.h - https://pastee.org/p5eap

knetconfig.cpp - https://pastee.org/q3sjp

knetconfig.h - https://pastee.org/dv5ka

main.cpp - https://pastee.org/5jkzq

parser.cpp - https://pastee.org/e7s4z

parser.h - https://pastee.org/58rsc

prefsdialog.ui - https://pastee.org/7yyj

prefsdialogimpl.cpp - https://pastee.org/t4qc8

prefsdialogimpl.h - https://pastee.org/2f32c

resources.h - https://pastee.org/ttdpq

statsframe.cpp - https://pastee.org/vx5fu

statsframe.h - https://pastee.org/rm8s2

utils.cpp - https://pastee.org/y3sm6

utils.h - https://pastee.org/z8ra2

Comment: That is a warning, not an error - it only tells you that the function takes a parameter it never uses (in fact that particular function does nothing at all). I suspect the problem lies somewhere else in the code.

Comment: This warning is the only indication of any problem, besides the crash, and it's in the configFile area, so I suspect it may be involved.  I can't save any changes to the knetrc file through the app, without it crashing.

Comment: I find that even when I right-click and About, then close About it crashes my app.  How would I narrow this down?

Comment: Compiling with debug symbols:# gdb knet
    Reading symbols from knet...done.
    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /usr/local/src/knetbuild/knet 
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
    QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
    QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
    QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
    QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
    [Inferior 1 (process 24933) exited normally]
    (gdb) bt
    No stack.
    (gdb)